# Photoshop CS6 - spacebar shortcut for hand tool has stopped working

Tags: macos, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6

In Photoshop **CS6**, the default behavior of depressing the spacebar as a shortcut for the Hand tool was working as expected, then stopped for no apparent reason. I have rebooted, closed browsers, shut down all other applications and deleted preferences and the problem persists. The spacebar works properly elsewhere, including Photoshop **CS4**.

Is there a keyboard shortcut setting I'm missing (I've checked Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts and can find nothing for the spacebar, and can not add it to the Hand tool).

This is on OSX Lion 10.7.4

Comment: There might be a solution in this place to reset your hand tool:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/375776

Comment: Thans for the reply. The link you posted shows how to delete PS preferences, which I've done repeatedly with no change.

Comment: I have this problem too, a lot. I still have yet to figure out what causes it, but a complete reboot of the system fixes it. (The same thing happens in Illustrator CS6 too.)

Comment: To anyone who is still having issues, THIS worked for me:

http://techne.alaya.net/?p=12012

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread, but I found it when Googling for the same issue, so I thought I would answer.

According to [this thread on Adobe's forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/636568), certain browsers or possibly specific browser extensions, such as 1Password or Anesidora, seem to foul up CS5/6's spacebar shortcut.

The solution seems to be simply to quit Safari / Chrome / Firefox and launch them again. Might need to quit/launch Photoshop too.

Worked for me with Chrome, but there's quite a few variables in the problems reported, so there doesn't seem to be a silver bullet.

Comment: Thanks a Ton.... It really save my keyboard from harassed and banged to the wall because that behavior...

Comment: No problem @TekYin, glad this helped someone!

Comment: Works for me - OSX Yosemite & quitting Chrome.

Comment: Very unusual, but worked for me, too. I had to close an open Chrome window (although not the whole application) with several Lynda.com tabs open in order for the Photoshop spacebar shortcuts to return. I also have 1Password and I had used it with Lynda.com in this session, but like @Leo says, there are quite a few variables.

Comment: I don't have 1Password and quitting Chrome and opening it again worked.

Comment: 1password was the culprit for me